# Deprecated mysql::server module in puppetlabs dashboard module, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, puppet, dashboard

I have installed the [puppetlabs dashboard module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/dashboard), but when I run

```
puppet agent --test
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: ERROR:  This class has been deprecated and the functionality
>   moved
>       into mysql::server.  If you run mysql::server without correctly calling
>       mysql:: server with the new override_options hash syntax you will revert
>       your MySQL to the stock settings.  Do not proceed without removing this
>       class and using mysql::server correctly.
>
> ```
> If you are brave you may set attempt_compatibility_mode in this class which
> attempts to automap the previous settings to appropriate calls to
> mysql::server at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/mysql/manifests/init.pp:89
> ```

I have tried fixing it based on [this](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/3516/how-to-install-mysql-error-this-class-has-been-deprecated/) answer, but I honestly don't know how to apply the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with new version of this module, you need to instantiate `mysql::server` and `mysql::client` and not anymore `mysql`

You might just replace your declaration from `mysql` by `mysql::server` (do not forget to check the parameters names have not changed).

Hope this helps.